# Reducing the Kronecker Delta

Tags: kronecker-product, kronecker-delta

I am not sure where my line of thinking for

$\delta_{ij} \delta_{ij} = \delta_{ii}$ is going wrong. Please help me find my error:

[image]

Comment: You're adding terms before the product, but notice that the repeated indices are across terms in the product. It was supposed only supposed to be terms of the form $$\delta_{ij}\delta_{ji} = \delta_{11}\delta_{11}+\delta_{12}\delta_{21} + \cdots$$ but your product introduces extraneous terms that don't belong like $\delta_{11}\delta_{33}$

Comment: That cleared up my confusion. Thank you!!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You cannot add the Kronecker indices before multiplying them fully out.